# Python/tkinter/canvas: mouse-down + drag + mouse-up events only return the mouse-down item tag?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

On a Python/tkinter/canvas: the user will click on one item, drag to another item and release. The items themselves are not dragged/moved; I only need the tags from both items. The problem I observe is that when mouse-down is on one item and then dragged to a different item for mouse-release, the canvas returns the first-item id#/tag as both event id#/tags.

The mouse coordinates report properly for both events, and the tags work properly in every other respect.

Is this a bug or implementation limitation? Are there any workarounds? Or am I doing it wrong?

Demo code below also at https://pastebin.com/MD9AuAUS

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from functools import partial


'''
Ctag Tester v1.0
29 February 2020
Written for Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) 
[MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 / Windows 10 / VS Code (ide)

This is a demo of a tkinter / canvas bug. Or something. (?)

1. Each of the two squares on the canvas should report its tag 
for a mouse-1-down and mouse-1-up event.

2. It always reports properly if you click and release on the same item.

3. PROBLEM: If you click down on one square and then drag to the other
square, the mouse-up event gives the same tag as the mouse-down event,
even though they did not occur on the same item.

4. The mouse x-y coordinates are also reported, and those always
report correctly wherever those two events occur.

5. What I assumed should happen is that the mouse-down event should get
the tag of the item that it occurs on, and the mouse-up event should get
the tag of the item that it occurs on.
'''


def main():
    program = TestProgram1()
    program.window.mainloop()

class TestProgram1:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title( "Ctag Tester v1.0" )
        self.window_width = 800
        self.window_height = 600
        self.window.minsize(self.window_width, self.window_height)
        self.window_position_x = 40
        self.window_position_y = 40
        self.window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (self.window_width, self.window_height, self.window_position_x, self.window_position_y))
        self.window.resizable(False, False)



        x_pos = 20
        y_pos = 20
        self.staticlabel_38 = tk.Label(master=self.window, text="mousedown xy:")
        self.staticlabel_38.place(x=x_pos, y=y_pos)
        x_pos = 180
        y_pos = 20
        self.staticlabel_42 = tk.Label(master=self.window, text="mouseup xy:")
        self.staticlabel_42.place(x=x_pos, y=y_pos)

        x_pos = 20
        y_pos = 50
        self.label_mousedown = tk.Label(master=self.window, text="[none]")
        self.label_mousedown.place(x=x_pos, y=y_pos)
        x_pos = 180
        y_pos = 50
        self.label_mouseup = tk.Label(master=self.window, text="[none]")
        self.label_mouseup.place(x=x_pos, y=y_pos)

        x_pos = 20
        y_pos = 100
        self.staticlabel_55 = tk.Label(master=self.window, text="mousedown tag:")
        self.staticlabel_55.place(x=x_pos, y=y_pos)
        x_pos = 180
        y_pos = 100
        self.staticlabel_59 = tk.Label(master=self.window, text="mouseup tag:")
        self.staticlabel_59.place(x=x_pos, y=y_pos)

        x_pos = 20
        y_pos = 130
        self.label_tagdown = tk.Label(master=self.window, text="[none]")
        self.label_tagdown.place(x=x_pos, y=y_pos)
        x_pos = 180
        y_pos = 130
        self.label_tagup = tk.Label(master=self.window, text="[none]")
        self.label_tagup.place(x=x_pos, y=y_pos)

        x_pos = 350
        y_pos = 40
        self.canvas1 = tk.Canvas(master=self.window, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas1.place(x=x_pos, y=y_pos)
        self.canvas1.create_rectangle(2, 2, 400, 400, outline='black', fill='white')

        target_1 = self.canvas1.create_rectangle(80, 80, 180, 180, outline='black', fill='green', tags=('greenbox'))
        self.canvas1.tag_bind('greenbox', '<Button-1>', partial(self.chart_item_mousedown_event, target_1))
        self.canvas1.tag_bind('greenbox', '<ButtonRelease-1>', partial(self.chart_item_mouseup_event, target_1))      

        target_2 = self.canvas1.create_rectangle(240, 180, 340, 280, outline='black', fill='red', tags=('redbox'))
        self.canvas1.tag_bind('redbox', '<Button-1>', partial(self.chart_item_mousedown_event, target_2))
        self.canvas1.tag_bind('redbox', '<ButtonRelease-1>', partial(self.chart_item_mouseup_event, target_2))



    def chart_item_mousedown_event(self, c_handle, event):
        temp_tag = self.canvas1.gettags(c_handle)
        if temp_tag == "":
            self.label_tagdown.config(text='[none]')
        else:
            self.label_tagdown.config(text=temp_tag)
        m_event = "x:" + str(event.x) + ", y:" + str(event.y)
        self.label_mousedown.config(text=m_event)



    def chart_item_mouseup_event(self, c_handle, event):
        temp_tag = self.canvas1.gettags(c_handle)
        if temp_tag == "":
            self.label_tagup.config(text='[none]')
        else:
            self.label_tagup.config(text=temp_tag)
        m_event = "x:" + str(event.x) + ", y:" + str(event.y)
        self.label_mouseup.config(text=m_event)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Read up on [Tkinter.Canvas.find_*-method's](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_closest-method)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, and it's not really a limitation either. It's simply how tkinter was designed to work. The widget and/or canvas item that gets the button press event is the one that will receive the subsequent release event.

You will need to have the code that is bound to the release event find the canvas item that is under the cursor.

For example, given an event object, here is how to find the canvas item nearest to the pointer:

```
canvas = event.widget
canvasx = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
canvasy = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
item = canvas.find_closest(canvasx, canvasy)
```